# A property of set of all continuous functions on the interval [0,1]

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

> Show that for every $g\in C([0,1])$ there exists a function $f\in C([0,1])$ such that
> $$f(x)-\int_0^x e^{-y}f(y)dy = g(x) $$

I don't know how I can go about proving this, I thought about using the Banach fixpoint theorem because I know that $C([a,b]); \ a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ is a Banach space with the supremum norm but I haven't really been able proceed any further, I need some help.

Comment: You are on the right track. Rewrite the equation such that it looks like $f(x)=...$ and consider the right hand side as an operator on $C$. Apply the Banach Theorem to this operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $h(x)=\int_0^{x}e^{-y}f(y)dy$. Then the equation can be written as $e^{x}h'(x)-h(x)=g(x)$ or $h'(x)-e^{-x}h(x)=e^{-x}g(x)$. This can be solved using an integrating factor: $\frac d {dx} (e^{-\int_0^{x} e^{-t}dt} h(x))=e^{-\int_0^{x} e^{-t}dt}e^{-x}g(x)$ and integration gives you $h(x)$. Since $h$ is continuously differentiable you can get $f$ from $f(x)=e^{x}h'(x)$.